# Sheets Arrayformula with IF, AND & OR

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I really need some help.

Is it possible to create an arrayformula in Google Sheets for this:

```
=
IF(AND(OR($F3>0,$G3>0),$G$1=TRUE),"A",
IF(AND(OR($H3>0,$I3>0),$I$1=True),"B",
IF(AND(OR($J3>0,$K3>0),$K$1=True),"C",
IF(AND(OR($L3>0,$M3>0),$M$1=True),"D",
""))))
```

I would like the `arrayformula` to cover each of the columns above e.g. `F3:F>0`, `G3:G>0`, etc.

Many, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF((((F3:F>0)+(G3:G>0))*(G1=TRUE)); "A";
 IF((((H3:H>0)+(I3:I>0))*(I1=TRUE)); "B";
 IF((((J3:J>0)+(K3:K>0))*(K1=TRUE)); "C";
 IF((((L3:L>0)+(M3:M>0))*(M1=TRUE)); "D"; )))))
```